# No sound output to USB headset

Tags: sound, output

Control centre then sound then Alsamixer then F6 and option 2 is my Plantronics headset.
I choose it but nothing seems to work
I am on new install of lxle v12.04.4 32bit
All works fine in Windows XP
I am a complete novice to Ubuntu so all help/advise appreciated
Ron

Answer (score 1):

- Install "pulseaudio  volume control"  from software center then launch it from multimedia menu
- Select output device tab, Scroll down to display the second device (usb audio) .
- Click "set as fallback" button to set it as default device, uncheck "mute" button , increase volume using the fader, maybe you will hear sound.

Comment: What if the second device doesn't appear eve if the headphones ae plugged in and turned on? And why don't the headphones show up in lsusb?

Comment: Could be a driver issue, try newer  Ubuntu version